# How to have the login screen through VNC in Oracle Linux?

Tags: centos, vnc, oracle-vm-server

Basically what I am looking for is similar feature like RDP on Windows. I should be able to view the login screen through VNC Viewer. Even if server is restarted I should still be able to access it through VNC Viewer. Currently someone has to first obtain the console through OVM (these are all VMs), login and only then is it possible to remote through VNC Viewer.
I know this question has been asked here previously [[ref1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67497/x11vnc-how-to-have-the-login-screen) [[ref2]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43398/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-vnc-server-alive-after-log-out) also [here](http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot) but so far I have been unsuccessful in my attempts. Can anyone provide a detailed guide on how to go about achieving this?

- OS:       Oracle Linux 5
- VNC rpm : vnc-server-4.1.2-14.el5_6.6

### Update 1 - VNC at User Level

Ok so I followed everything listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/147109/automatically-start-vnc-server-on-startup)

- Logged in to the server through PuTTY using root (because that's the acount I need to use for logging in through VNC).
- Ran vncpasswd  and set the VNC login password.
- Saved the [script](https://superuser.com/a/147112/213025)  as `/etc/init.d/vncserver` after changing the following parameters:

  - USER="root"
  - DISPLAY="1"
- Did `chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver`.
- Did `chkconfig --level 2345 vncserver on`.
- Did `vi /root/.vnc/xstartup` and uncommented the lines:

  ```bsh
  unset SESSION_MANAGER
  exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
  ```

  and changed last line from `twm &` to `startx &` (since I'm using GNOME).
- Restarted the server.

Now I could successfully remote to the server through VNC Viewer. This works even if server is restarted. However, **it bypasses the lock screen and does not prompt for password**. For this I had to set up a password through **System > Preferences > Remote Desktop**.
**Important Note:** As @slm described below, this method provides VNC access at user level. Meaning you can create multiple users and provide them VNC access separately. Each user will have a unique desktop. This wasn't exactly what I was looking for though!

### Update 2 - VNC at System Level, like RDP on Windows

After implementing @slm's solution, I realised that this was what I actually had in mind when I asked this question. I followed exactly what he said. It's a lot simpler! Couple of things I would like to add:

- I didn't need to install x11vnc. I used only the vnc rpm that was installed by default.
- `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file was missing. To create it I did the following:  [(Source)](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_xorg.conf)

  - As root run: `Xorg :1 -configure`. This will create the file /root/xorg.conf.new
  - `cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

I followed rest of the instructions. Restarted gdm and Voila! It worked! I was able to see the login screen through VNC Viewer, exactly like RDP on Windows. It worked even after server restart. Great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to [@Timo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109737/7453) there sounds like there are 3 ways to setup VNC access.

1. At the user level (that's what you're using now)
2. At the system level
3. At the Host level (when running inside of a VM) - this is Timo's suggestion

**NOTE:** This tutorial shows how to do **#1**, it's titled: [How to install VNC server on CentOS 6](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-centos-6/).

If you think for a second **#3** is actually just another form of **#1** & **#2**, depending on where you provide access to the desktop. At the user level (**#1**) or at the system level, (**#2**).

So I think what you want is actually **#2**. To get this type of setup working there are basically 2 methods that I'm aware of.

#### x11vnc

You can install the package `x11vnc` and then use this to gain access to the current X11 session on a remote system. It's generally in most of the Red Hat based distro repos so I won't cover installation, but once installed you'd `ssh` into a system that you want to access the console display (:0.0), and manually run it like so:

```
$ x11vnc -nopw -display :0.0
```

There are methods for making this more permanent so that it just runs as part of the session. One such method is discussed in this blog post, titled: [x11vnc on CentOS5 with GDM](http://iansworld-nz.blogspot.com/2009/06/x11vnc-on-centos5-with-gdm.html).

#### X11 + vnc

The second method is to install a module/driver into X11 so that you can connect to any running X11 desktop. The one I'm familiar with is called `vnc`. This driver needs to be installed into the host system's X setup so that you can access the system's login manager. I'm not sure what it is on Oracle (most likely it's GDM - GNOME Display Manager) since it derives from RHEL.

The good news is that if you'e installed the package `vnc-server` you already have the X11 driver installed. Simply add this to your host system's X11 setup.

First you'll need to add this line to your `xorg.conf`'s `Module` section:

```
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Module"
  Load "vnc"
EndSection
```

Next you'll need to add several lines to this same files `Screen` section:

```
Option "SecurityTypes" "VncAuth"
Option "UserPasswdVerifier" "VncAuth"
Option "PasswordFile" "/root/.vnc/passwd"
```

Last setup a password for this connection, using the tool `vncpasswd`, then restart X.

#### References

- [CentOS 5 Wiki - HowTos - VNC-Server](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server)
- [[CentOS] How to setup VNC for GDM access on 6.3](http://grokbase.com/t/centos/centos/131pdprw16/how-to-setup-vnc-for-gdm-access-on-6-3)

Comment: Hi...would you please see my updates.

Comment: @Gh0sT - for starters you could just disable `vncserver` the service. `chkconfig --level 2345 vncserver off`. Then either reboot or stop it if it's started. `/etc/init.d/vncserver stop`.

Comment: @Gh0sT - Try the command `yum search libvnc.so` to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `vnc-server` on the server itself, you should connect (using VNC) to the OVM directly via the settings of your VirtualMachine: Settings → Display → Remote Display.

On that TAB enable the server (make sure you mark the port number you select), that is a VNC server and you can connect with your normal client.